# In PHP, how to display array contents in a table

Tags: php, mysql, ascii-art

If I do a select in the MySQL client, I will have output that looks like this:

```
mysql> select * FROM `group` LIMIT 2;
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| group_id | group_supergroup_id | group_deletable | group_label |
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|        1 |                   4 |               0 | defaut      |
|        8 |                   1 |               1 | dbdfg       |
+----------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

How can I convert a PDO `fetch` (or `fetchAll`) array in a table like that?

Here's a code usage example:

```
$prep = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `group` LIMIT 2;');
$arr = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo renderMySQLTable($arr);
```

Comment: PDO can do no good itself... it's just a tool, used by someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something close to what *mysql client* outputs:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'group_id'            => '1',
        'group_supergroup_id' => '4',
        'group_deletable'     => '0',
        'group_label'         => 'default',
    ),
    array(
        'group_id'            => '8',
        'group_supergroup_id' => '1',
        'group_deletable'     => '1',
        'group_label'         => 'dbdfg',
    ),
);

if ( empty($data) ) {
    echo "Empty set";
} else {
    // determine widths of titles
    $colWidths = array();
    foreach ( $data[0] as $title => $value ) {
        $colWidths[$title] = strlen($title);
    }
    // determine widths of columns
    foreach ( $data as $row ) {
        foreach ( $row as $title => $value ) {
            if ( is_null($value) ) {
                $value = 'NULL';
            }
            if ( $colWidths[$title] < strlen($value) ) {
                $colWidths[$title] = strlen($value);
            }
        }
    }
    // generate horizontal border
    $horizontalBorder = '+';
    foreach ( $colWidths as $title => $width ) {
        $horizontalBorder .= str_repeat('-', $width + 2) . "+";
    }
    $horizontalBorder .= "\n";
    // print titles
    echo $horizontalBorder;
    echo '|';
    foreach ( $data[0] as $title => $value ) {
        printf(" %-{$colWidths[$title]}s |", $title);
    }
    echo "\n";
    echo $horizontalBorder;
    // print contents
    foreach ( $data as $row ) {
        echo "|";
        foreach ( $row as $title => $value ) {
            if ( is_null($value) ) {
                $value = 'NULL';
            }
            printf(" %-{$colWidths[$title]}s |", $value);
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
    echo $horizontalBorder;
}
```

Comment: It has a problem with UTF-8 accent ( counting them as 2chr, so it mess with the space padding), but overal that works !

Comment: Use `mb_strlen()` instead of `strlen()` for UTF8. Don't forget to set internal encoding with `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` before using any `mb_` function.

Answer (score 1):

non-pdo aproach though :)

```
function renderMySQLTable($query) {
  echo `mysql -H -e"$query"`;
}
```

for the array it's not that hard. a few loops and you've got you need. 
start from running `print_r($arr)`  to see it's structure

Comment: Then how can this generate a table ?, wouldn't it just output mysql -H -w "$query" ? Are the backtick have a special meaning ?

Comment: Forget it. You shouldn't use it anyway, it was more a trick. Learn how to handle arrays, friend, it's way more important

Comment: Hum ok, but print_r (as var_export and var_dump) doesn't return a mysql-like representation of a table. My question was not about understanding how array works -- I'm more than ok with that part -- it was on how to have a clean & adaptable code that works well to display a table in a specific format. This kind of representation need to deal with maximal column content size and all that stuff, and I'm pretty sure that someone already have made a method for it.

Comment: Nope, you aren't ok with that part. Learn how to handle arrays to be able to write these 2 simple arrays yourself. Cheers

Comment: @FMaz the backticks have a special meaning. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php You usually want to use `exec()` instead though.

Comment: @FMaz008, even if anyone already has a function/method for that, it is much faster to write it yourself than to find it. It is not something like full implementation of FTP protocol in PHP, it is really very simple task that takes like 10 minutes of lazy coding to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

use Table, and give a bit of style in css.

```
echo "<table class='datasheet'>";
foreach($arr as $a)
{
    echo "<tr>";
        foreach($a as $v)
        {
                echo "<td>$v</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Don't forget the column headers. A loop with mysql_num_fields()/mysql_fetch_field() can generate that.

Comment: Hum, I know I didn't explicitly specified it, but I really need a TXT output.