# php output array in table format

Tags: php

I am trying to display the array data in a specific way in a table, so I am needing to format my array like this:

```
               Leafy Life - Aspley - All Green
Callistemon1 -     33     -        - 
Callistemon2 -            -        - 3.59
Acronychia   -            -  22.5  -
```

I have tried many times, but my knowledge is limited and would really appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction, or even if you have time to adjust my code that would be very much appreciated.
<?php

```
$options = array(
array("plant" => "Callistemon Kings Park Special 300 mm","nursery" => "A Leafy Life","price" => "33"),
array("plant" => "Callistemon Kings Park Special 300 mm","nursery" => "Alpine Nurseries Alstonville","price" => "23"),
array("plant" => "Callistemon Kings Park Special 140 mm","nursery" => "All Green Nursery","price" => "3.59"),
array("plant" => "Acronychia imperforata 300 mm","nursery" => "Aspley Nursery","price" => "22.5"),
array("plant" => "Acronychia imperforata 300 mm","nursery" => "All Green Nursery","price" => "23"),
array("plant" => "Metrosideros collina Little Dugald  140 mm","nursery" => "Accent Plants","price" => "5.25"),
);

$newOptions = array();
foreach ($options as $option) {
 $plant = $option['plant'];
 $nursery = $option['nursery'];
 $price = $option['price'];

 $newOptions[$plant][$nursery] = $price;
}

print_r($newOptions);

echo "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='2'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<th></th>";
foreach($newOptions as $key => $row) 
{ 
    foreach($row as $k => $v) 
    {
        print_r($k);
        echo "<th>";
        echo $k;
        echo "</th>";
    }       
}
echo "</thead>";

echo "<tbody>";
$i=0;
foreach($newOptions as $keys => $rows) 
{ 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $keys;
    echo "</td>";

    foreach($rows as $v) 
    {
        
            echo "<td>";
            echo "&nbsp;". $i;
            echo "</td>";
        
        $i++;
        echo "<td>";
        echo $v;
        echo "</td>";
        
    }
    
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";


?>
```

Comment: Are you stuck with the current format of $options or can that be changed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566621/in-php-how-to-display-array-contents-in-a-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change structure of the array like this -

```
$Headers = array();
$headers[1] = "Leafy Life";
$headers[2] = "Aspley";
$headers[3] = "All Green";

$firstCloumnEntries = array();
$firstCloumnEntries[1] = "Callistemon1";
$firstCloumnEntries[2] = "Callistemon2";
$firstCloumnEntries[3] = "Acronychia";

$values = array();
$values[1] = array(); // this will have all values for first row;
$values[1][1] = "33";

$values[2] = array(); // this will have all values for second row;
$values[2][3] = "3.59";

$values[1] = array(); // this will have all values for third row;
$values[3][2] = "22.5";
```

Now while displaying - first add everything from all column "header" array.

Then for each row - use "firstCloumnEntries" array to get first value using index of the loop.
    Write an inner loop to print corresponding row values. Before printing that value make use of `isset()`.

Index "0" is purposely eliminated as we do not have any value in 0th column 0th row.
Index in the header array or in firstCloumnEntries array will help us to understand ID of the element inside it, e.g 1 is ID for "Leafy Life", 2 is for "Aspley" and so on.. using this we can add more headers with new IDs and more firstCloumnEntries with more IDs.
This will help in adding dynamic content and makes looping easy.